# Автоматический выбор значения в select

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть два селекта выбора стран. "Откуда" и "куда". 
Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе в одном из селектов любой страны, во второй селект автоматически добавлялась страна с id = 220. 
И обратно. При замене значения во втором селекте (с id = 220) на другой, в первом селекте ставится страна с id = 220.
Помогите плиз.

```
<div class="home-main-block-data_right">
<div class="form-group">
    <p>Откуда</p>

    <table class="tb_m">
        <tr>
            <td>Откуда</td>
            <td class="form-group_item">
                <select onchange="calc();" id="country-from" name="country-from">
                    <?php foreach(Calc_zones::getCountriesListForSelectByLang(LANG) as $country){ ?>
                        <option <?php if($country['id'] == 220){ ?>selected<?php } ?> value="<?=$country['id']?>"><?=$country['title']?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select></td>
        </tr>            
    </table>

    <p>Куда</p>

    <table class="tb_m">
        <tr>
            <td>Куда</td>
            <td class="form-group_item">
                <select onchange="calc();" id="country-in" name="country-in">
                    <?php foreach(Calc_zones::getCountriesListForSelectByLang(LANG) as $country){ ?>
                        <option <?php if($country['id'] == 223){ ?>selected<?php } ?> value="<?=$country['id']?>"><?=$country['title']?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select></td>
        </tr>            
    </table>

</div>
```